# Enabling MathML in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mathml

I'd like to ask, how would I go about enabling MathML in Chrome? I am visiting the MDN site about the `Math` object and the site warns me MathML is not enabled. Any help?

Comment: Neither chrome nor edge/ie support MathML. There's nothing you can do as a user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are user, you have :

- from release 109 (10/12/2022) : [Igalia](https://www.igalia.com/) company work added MathML support [status of the implemenation](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5240822173794304).
- or to use [Mozilla FireFox or others](https://www.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/browsers/).

If you are a developer :

- Android

  - use [GeckoView](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView).
  - use WebView. MathML is enabled by default from release 109 (12/01/202). Extended Glyphs are still missing.
- Java (Linux, Mac, Windows, ..., arch)

  - [JavaFX WiebView](https://openjfx.io)
- Else

  - the [WebKit port](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki) in your development tool or platform.

    - Direct link to listed [WPE WebKit](https://wpewebkit.org/) example.

Answer (score 3):

MathML is not available in Chrome. Although the C/C++ source code is still there,  it is not used when building Chrome, so there is no way to enable it [(more info)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152430#c35).

You can still use other third party solutions like [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) or [MathType Web](https://docs.wiris.com/en/mathtype/mathtype_web/start).

Answer (score 1):

Try this chrome extension, Math Anywhere:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/math-anywhere/gebhifiddmaaeecbaiemfpejghjdjmhc/related?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

"MathML," the markup to display mathematical notations such as fractions and exponents and such, as coded in examples on Wikipedia, works in current Chrome display by first typing "chrome://flags" into Chrome's address bar and then, on the resulting displayed page, setting "Experimental WebAssembly" to enabled and relaunching Chrome.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

MathML support will ship with Chrome 109 (release date ~Dec 2022).

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3i02Yh3F9s

You can already test it in Chrome's unstable channel.